# How to set up web api versioning?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, aspnet-api-versioning

Hello i have a controller and i want to version its routes.However i do not want the api-version to be added in the querystring but in the begining of the url , after the controller name:

**Typical Path**:  `/api/admin/get-computer/1`
**Versioned Path**:  `/api/admin/V[version]/get-computer/1`

I do not understand how to configure the controller and the `UseMvc` extension from the `Startup`:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("/api/admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("/get-computer")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Catalog>> GetComputerAsync1(int id) {
        return null;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("/get-computer")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Catalog>> GetCatalogAsync2(int id) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());

            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Admin}/V[???]/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

**Preferred usage**

```
"/api/admin/V1/get-computer/3"
 "/api/admin/V2/get-computer/4"
```

How can i achieve this ? What is the supposed form of the route template in the `UseMvc` extension ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the package Microsoft.AspnetCore.Mvc.ApiVersioning (if you havent already done so).

Configure the versioning services in your Startup -> ConfigureServices(...) by adding this:

`services.AddApiVersioning();`

Then in your `[Route()]` attribute on your controller insert the api version parameter as follows:

`[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/admin")]`
This enables your controller to be hit with urls like "api/v1.0/admin". You can remove the 'v' before the {version} parameter if you do not want it.

For further details let me refer you to the [documentation on url versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-via-the-URL-Path)

Comment: I have already installed this package.Is there anyway in which i don't have to decorate the `Route` above the controller ? I want all controllers to have the same template.

Comment: then all you need is to add {version:apiVersion} parameter in your route attribute. Also check the docs in the link i have provided for additional information

Comment: To not map on every controller, in your template you can still add the version parameter. e.g `template: "{controller=Admin}/V{version:apiversion}/{action=Index}/{id?}"`. I havent tested this, but since the `apiVersion` constraint is added into the MVC's routeOptions, it should work.

Comment: Also how do you set up api-versioning in post-request?

Comment: "post-request" - do you mean an HTTP POST request?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian there's nothing special about `POST`. You can apply API versions to any endpoint with any HTTP method as you've already done. If you want to configure the same prefix for all of your controllers, I would recommend using the _Application Model_ and registering a custom `IApplicationModelProvider` that wires up the prefix in all `ControllerModel` instances.